# To search for a file at FTP

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I want to find if a file exists at FTP using if-exist filename -else statement using FTP batch script which is as follows:

```
ftp.txt open ftp.mysite.com
ftp.txt username
ftp.txt password
ftp.txt if exist filename (echo file exists) else (echo file doesn't exist)
ftp.txt quit
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

the if-exist line above does not work.
Is there any other way to search?

Comment: .bat files are primitive enough.  DOS/Windows ftp scripts are even more primitive (i.e. *extremely* limiting).  Strong suggestion: write a VBScript (or Perl or Python or VB.Net script) that does your FTP ... and handles the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the logic in the FTP script.

Call the ftp.txt script from a batch file.  Within your ftp.txt script, just do a GET on your file.  If the file is there, it'll be downloaded to the local directory.  Otherwise, it won't.  After calling the FTP script, check the file's existence in your local directory using standard DOS batch commands, i.e.:

```
@echo off

:FETCHFILE
ftp -s:ftp.txt
IF EXIST filetocheckfor.txt (
   REM the file was there, so do something
) ELSE
   echo Trying again...
   REM ping "sleep" would go here
   GOTO FETCHFILE
)
```

If you want to build a delay into your retries, perform a "sleep" by pinging a bogus IP address, as described in this post:
http://www.dullsharpness.com/2010/06/14/elapsed-timer-using-pure-ms-dos/

Comment: Is this correct because if I do a get on a file that doesn't exists it creates it locally but will be empty. Sadly in my case the file is just a flag file and will be empty if it exists on the ftp server anyway so I can't tell the difference if it really exists or not. Why is this so complicated btw. Seems like a fairly common request to see if a file exists. FTP needs to be updated :)