# check existing file in ftp batch file

Tags: batch-file, dom, command-line, ftp

i want to copy a file sample.zip from local to FTP, but before that i have to check whether a file with sample.zip exist in FTP folder. if exist no need to execute mput command(no need to copy), below is my code.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo user FTP003 > ftpcmd.dat
echo KL#!RY169>> ftpcmd.dat
:: change local directory,where sample.zip exist
ECHO LCD "C:\folder1\test">> ftpcmd.dat
:: Change the Remote Directory to copy file
ECHO CD /Releases/Office >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO PWD >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO BINARY >> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO prompt >> ftpcmd.dat
:: Need to verify whether sample.zip file exist in this location if exist dont copy, not exist need to copy
echo MPUT sample.zip>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 182.72.200.181
DEL ftpcmd.dat
```

please help me, am new to batch file scripting...

Comment: Or [To search for a file at FTP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9247313/850848).

Comment: ftp clients and servers have a wide variety of features and limitations. You'll save yourself headaches in the future by using super-basic `ftp` cmds (certain to be available on all servers and clients). Capture `ftp` output of `cd /remote/dir ; dir` into a local/tmp file and then see if the filename you need is in that list. If found, then run `ftp` to get the file. Good luck.

Comment: hi guys thanks for your information, i just store the ls of remote directory in ftpcmd.dat (temp file), but its not working as expected below is my code.

Comment: `type ftpcmd.dat | findstr "palaccounts" | find ".zip" && echo FILE IS OUT THERE && goto :skip_file_is_not_there`

Comment: update tne code in your Q. But I don't get now `&& goto :skip_file_is_not_there` works on the end of that chain of logic, dont you want `|| goto: skipfile`? But it seems like your close. Did you actually look in `ftpcmd.dat`? (Do you know file exists on remote? Is it in that file?) If so then your code is wrong. At this point we don't know which, because of a lack of evidence. Good luck!